# Using grunt in Symfony project with different bundles

Tags: symfony, gruntjs, bower

I'm looking for some advice & tips on how you deal with Grunt tasks in a Symfony project containing different bundles.

For example:
I created a "backendBundle" which contains a basic login system and basic UI for general web applications. The UI uses Twitter bootstrap, some parts of jQuery UI and it also contains some of my own JS and CSS. This bundle is in a private git repo.

I also created a second bundle (CMSBundle) which imports inherits BackendBundle and adds some CMS functionalities to the backend. The CMSBundle obviously uses the UI of BackendBundle, but has some extra CSS/JS of its own.

A website project is a symfony project which includes both bundles using composer, so the bundles are downloaded to the vendor folder.

The problem is that my Gruntfile.js resides in the root folder of the project (aka website), and has no knowledge of the the imported bundles' requirements.

Is there a way to include/import tasks provided by a specific bundle in a seperate Gruntfile.js file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't having any direct experience with making what you describe work across multiple bundles, but it seems like [Grunt Hub](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub) may accomplish what you're after.  You'd just need to ensure that it (Grunt Hub) can locate your Gruntfile.js for each bundle, either through a file globbing pattern or static path(s).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool, keep us posted if you give it a go!

Comment: @Webberig so is it was useful?

Comment: Not in my use case, no. I needed something that would "merge" lists of files into one and the same task. I resolved it by creating .json files in each bundle and then load these json files into my Gruntfile configuration programmatically. Probably not the best scalable solution, but it works in my case...